# Как обновлять изображение в ячейке UICollectionView после полной загрузки через AlamofireImage или SDWebImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimage, alamofire

Когда следует обновлять ячейку, чтобы отобразить загруженное изображение? Если выполнять `self.collectionView?.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])` в `completed: у метода sd_setImage`, то происходит зацикливание

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
  cell.avatarImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: user[indexPath.row].avatarURL)!, placeholderImage: UIImage.defaultAvatar())
  return cell
}
```

В AlamofireImage такая же ситуация

Comment: а можно посмотреть весь код о котором идет речь?

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.avatarImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: user[indexPath.row].avatarURL)!, 
                             placeholderImage: UIImage.defaultAvatar(),
                             options: SDWebImageOptions.retryFailed,                    
                             completed: { (image, _, _, _) in
                               cell.avatarImage.image = image
})
```